# Neurogensis in CNS invloves apoptosis of scar cells?

Tags: neuroscience, measurement, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurogenesis

Say there's neurogensis in a brain area that seems to "allow" it, like the Hipocampus, Striatum, and so forth.

Does this neurogensis might be preceded in the apoptosis of scar cells, and then, in the same area where the scar cell was removed, the neurogenesis takes place?

The purpose of this question is to understand if neurogensis would generally be preceded by apoptosis of a scar cell, and the new neuron will replace the scar cell, virtually, in its exact location.